# How to install gitorious in ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: github, ubuntu-18.04, gitorious

I'm using [this](https://github.com/gitorious/ce-installer) tutorial currently, and it does not work anyway.

```
Following information will be used to generate configuration file and SSL certificate:
  hostname (FQDN): lorena.local

+- Installing ansible...
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-pt_BR) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-pt) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54

+- Oops, a problem occurred.
+- Usually it happens when there's a network problem (probably timeout during package installation).
+- It is safe to run this script again.
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Did you clone and `cd` into the repository before trying to run that command?

Comment: @jwodder Got it! Thanks! But now I have an error.